# 2D char array dynamically realocation failure

Tags: c, char, dynamic-arrays

This is the code snippet. The dictionary format is:{word word \n word word \n...}

The program seems to fail the second time it is reallocating the 2D array roWords and i cant figuire it why.

In the declaration: char ** roWords = NULL, **enWords == NULL;

```
while (fgets(buffer, 100, dictionary))
    {
        counter++;

        roWords = (char**)realloc(roWords, sizeof(char*)* counter );
        enWords = (char**)realloc(enWords, sizeof(char*)* counter );

        p = strtok(buffer, " \n");


        roWords[counter - 1] = NULL;
        roWords[counter - 1] = (char*)realloc(roWords, sizeof(char)* strlen(p));
        strcpy(roWords[counter - 1], p);


        p = strtok(NULL, " \n");


        enWords[counter - 1] = NULL;
        enWords[counter - 1] = (char*)realloc(enWords, sizeof(char)* strlen(p));
        strcpy(enWords[counter - 1], p);


    }
```

Comment: How does it fall? Is there an error message?

Comment: Remember to allocate one extra char for the terminating `'\0'`. Also, `realloc`ing after setting looks a bit more complex than it should. It's maybe clearer to use `malloc` for allocating memory for the words.

Comment: The program works well for the first loop but when it reads the second line from de dictionray file it enters again the function, wich is good, it increments counter, wich is also god but when he enters again the "roWords = (char**)realloc(roWords, sizeof(char*)* counter );" it shows debug Assertion Failed. Any sugestions?

Comment: Could the error be that `p` is `NULL` and that the assertion fails in `strlen`?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 100, dictionary))
{
    counter++;

    if (counter == 1)
    {
        roWords = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        enWords = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    }
    else
    {
        roWords = (char**)realloc(roWords, sizeof(char*)* counter);
        enWords = (char**)realloc(enWords, sizeof(char*)* counter);
    }

    p = strtok(buffer, " \n");


    roWords[counter - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(p) + 1));
    strcpy(roWords[counter - 1], p);
    roWords[counter - 1][strlen(p)] = '\0';

    p = strtok(NULL, " \n");


    enWords[counter - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(p) + 1));
    strcpy(enWords[counter - 1], p);
    enWords[counter - 1][strlen(p)] = '\0';

}
```

Comment: `strtok(buffer, " \n");` does not always remove the `'\n'`.  Try it when `buffer` --> `"\n"`.  The `'\n'` remains.